# Physics2D.OverLapBox detects objects that should be ignored

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using a script that looks at the tiles around my GameObject to see if it can detect a collider, through Physics2D.OverlapBox. My problem is that my Player should be ignored by the OverLapBox, as I've set it to look at layers it isn't in, but it is detected everytime.

My Player is in the "Default" layer.

```
private void SpawnBasicWalls()
{
    int layersToScan = LayerMask.GetMask("Floor", "Wall");
    //for each tile around this tile
    for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
        {
            Vector2 targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x + x, transform.position.y + y);
            Collider2D hit = Physics2D.OverlapBox(targetPos, Vector2.one * 0.8f, layersToScan);
            //if there isn't a tile around
            if (!hit)
            {
                //Add a wall in that empty adjacent tile.
                GameObject goWall = Instantiate(dungMan.wallPrefab, targetPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                goWall.name = dungMan.wallPrefab.name;
                goWall.transform.SetParent(dungMan.transform);

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(hit);
            }
        }
    }
    //Once it's done, the gameobject is useless and thus is destroyed
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Can you try accepting layermask filters via inspector first? Add a `public LayerMask layersToScan` around the top of the class

Comment: @Kaynn I tried that, and then setting them in the inspector, but the player is still being detected, unfortunately.

Comment: werid, could you include a screenshot of the inspector on the player game-object? (Also, does the player have child game-objects?)

Comment: @Kaynn [Player Inspector](https://imgur.com/a/doZQr4b), hopefully that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Physics2D.OverlapBox(targetPos, Vector2.one * 0.8f, layersToScan)` is basically calling `Physics2D.OverlapBox(point, size, angle)` - which means you are sending the layers (casted to int) as an angle.

You need to use one of the overloads that receive a layermask, and make sure you pass it in the right parameter.